# Selenium - ASP.NET generated IDs (JQuery like selection)

Tags: asp.net, xpath, selenium, inamingcontainer

JQuery supports a syntax of `$("span[id$='Label1']")` to allow selection of ASP.NET INamingContainer generated ID's that have been prefixed with "*ct100$...*".

We are using Selenium and are looking for a similar way to select elements, ignoring the prefixes that ASP.NET generates.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
//span[@id[substring(.,string-length()-5)='Label1']]
```

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can do it using XPath selectors like this:

`//div[ends-with(text(), 'MyControlId')]`

but I have a feeling that you can't use the `ends-with` function with Selenium as it's not part of XPath 1.0. You might need something more ugly like this:

`//div[substring(text(), string-length(text()), 11)='MyControlId']`

Answer (score 0):

If the project is in .Net 4 its now possible to have static naming of dynamic controls.

Read here http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=492

Makes life a bit easier if you have the luxury to have it done this way. Otherwise a proper formed XPath will work (But is deadly slow test IE)

Cheers,
Stefan

Comment: Thanks for that information, definitely a good option to have. I actually just learned about this feature today in a separate but related question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461463/asp-net-inamingcontainer-optional-prefixes)